# use tag as biblatex key

Tags: biblatex

I see there are many styles for `biblatex` to generate the "keys" automatically in the bibliography, but I would like to use the actual cite key, so that I can completely customise it myself.

For instance if my entry is

```
@article{Th,
    Author = {Dude},
    Title = {thing}}
```

I would like that the text produced to be "this thing is said in [Th]" and I would like the reference to appear as:

> [Th] Dude, thing

It seems so simple but  cannot find what "`style`" this is. It seems to be the "`abstract`" style but `biblatex` tells me "`style abstract not found`".

Edit: the reason why I use biblatex is because I need two separate bibliographies based on some keyword, so if someone knows a way to do that with traditional bibtex (whatever that means), I'll take it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naively, I would have thought that

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{entrykey}
  }
}
```

should work for an `alphabetic` base style (and would be one of the most idiomatic solutions). That does not seem to be the case for Biber 2.12, so I opened https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/259 at the Biber bug tracker.

*edit* As [PLK answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481998/35864)

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{citekey}
  }
}
```

`citekey` instead of `entrykey` works. In the Biber versions from 2.13 onwards `entrykey` is also accepted.

---

In the meantime here is a work-around that copies the `entrykey` to the `shorthand` field. Since the `alphabetic` style uses the `shorthand` field as an 'override' for the label, copying the `entrykey` to that field will cause the `entrykey` to be the label. The mapping will not overwrite an existing `shorthand`. If you want that you can add `[overwrite=true]` to the `\map` directive. You can read more about source maps in the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), §4.5.3 *Dynamic Modification of Data* (pp. 182-193). Essentially source maps allow you to manipulate the contents of fields of `.bib` entries dynamically from the `.tex` source.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey]
      \step[fieldset=shorthand, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with entrykeys as label]

Note that this kind of label generation goes a bit against the idea of `biblatex` (and BibTeX). Usually most labels should be generated by Biber/BibTeX automatically and only occasionally you may want to overrule something with `shorthand`. Note that `biblatex`'s label creation is fully customisable, so if you can state your desired labels in algorithmic terms that `biblatex` understands, that would be the preferred solution. The entry keys should really be purely internal.

---

The `abstract` style you refer to in the question is presumably the BibTeX style `abstract.bst`. BibTeX's `.bst` styles are completely incompatible with `biblatex` and can not be used with that package. The `biblatex` styles `debug` and `draft` might also be interesting, though they should usually not be used in normal documents and their output is probably less suitable for what you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess I will look for something more simple as usually, when I add something complex that I don't understand, later that generates errors that I don't understand and I lose tons of time. Also, the reason why I use biblatex is because I need two separate bibliographies based on some keyword, so if someone knows a way to do that with traditional bibtex (whatever that means), I'll take it!

Comment: @kaleidoscop There are other possible ways to achieve a similar effect, but I believe that this method is one of the more natural/idiomatic solutions. I'll add some explanatory words. If there is still something left unclear, please don't hesitate to ask. Don't take the final bit of the answer as an attempt to dissuade you to use `biblatex`. There are ways to separate bibliographies with BibTeX, but with `biblatex` that is usually much easier to pull off.

Comment: I tried and it does not work, it leaves the alphabetic style. I actually replaced "biber" with "bibtex8" because I wanted to avoid installing something else. Is it the reason why it failed?

Comment: @kaleidoscop Yes, you *must* use Biber for `\DeclareSourcemap` to work.

Comment: One of the problem is for names that are two fold, such as "Jonhson-Smith", the alphabetic style naturally writes [JS] when I would like ieally [Js]. Do you think I could customise in this way?

Comment: @kaleidoscop Looks tricky, but might be possible (with Biber). If you ask a new question about that with a few example entries I might be able to help, but don't get your hopes up too high.

Comment: Ok it took me a while to install macports, then biber, and then removing all underscores from my entries, but it finally worked! Thanks

Comment: @kaleidoscop Biber should be available in any TeX live (MacTeX) installation via `tlmgr`, so I don't think you need macports (and if the rest of your TeX system does not come from macports, you may even end up with version conflicts if the two fall out of sync). I would have expected that underscores would be as problematic with BibTeX as they are with Biber (if you use `biblatex`, that is): Underscores are fine in entry keys (but of course not if you print the keys ...) and problematic in fields that are interpreted as normal text.

Answer (score 1):

This is already supported via the pseudo-key `citekey`:

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{citekey}
  }
}
```

I will probably add `entrykey` as an alias for compatibility with sourcemaps in the next version.

Comment: Ugh ... I should really start reading the documentation. For people like me the alias `entrykey` would be great.