# Customize biblatex: no "a" in citekey

Tags: biblatex

I use `biblatex` as you can see in the example below. But sadly  `\printbibliography` is not producing the layout as I wish.

Currently:

> [Buch00a] Name, V.: Titel. Hrsg. von Name, V. Bd. Auflage. Ort: Verlag, 1996.

Desired:

> [Buch00] Name, V.; Name, V (Hrsg.): Titel. Auflage. Ort: Verlag, 1996.

How can I hide the "a" in citekey?

Can anybody help me in order to customize the book entry in `biblatex`?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,ngerman]{scrbook}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.2}
%---package, default----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm} %SpringerShaker
%---package, tikz, eps in pdf--------------------------------------------------
%%%\usepackage{subfigure}


%--new lit--------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
        backend=biber,
%       style=numeric, %> for counting
        style=alphabetic,
        firstinits=true,
        maxbibnames=99,
        maxcitenames=1
        %backref=true
]{biblatex}
%
%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{% 
                %byeditor ={\unspace\mkbibparens {Hrrsg\adddot})}, 
        andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}}
                }             
%        editor = {(Hrsg.)}, 
%        editors = {(Hrsg.)}}
%
%bibkey in citiation
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\thefield{entrykey}}

%Hrsg with ()
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{editorstype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

%
% Titel nicht schräg
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{#1}

% Journal Titel nicht schräg
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
%        
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first} %Autoren immer Nachname, Vorname sortieren
%
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space} %Semikolon zum trennen der Autoren
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} %Zwischen Autor und Titel Doppelpunkt, kein Punkt


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% for final 
\defbibfilter{firstlev}{
  type=article or
    type=book or
    type=thesis or
    type=report or
    type=inproceedings
}

\defbibfilter{secondlev}{
  type=manual
}

% headings in lit
\defbibheading{firstlevel}{%
    \chapter{Literaturverzeichnis}
  %\section{Artikel, Bücher und Hochschulschriften}
}
\defbibheading{secondlevel}{%
  \section*{Manuals}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%
\addbibresource{LitExampleBib.bib} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% Start Doc %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\cite{Buch00}
\cite{Buch01}
\cite{Article00}
\cite{Phd00}
\cite{Techreport00}
\cite{Manual00}
\cite{Conf00}


%%%%%%%%%%%% for final Diss
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\printbibliography[filter=firstlev, heading=firstlevel]
\printbibliography[filter=secondlev, heading=secondlevel]


%%%% END %%%%%%%%%%%%5555%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

And here is the `.bib` source: LitExampleBib.bib

```
@Article{Article00,
  author    = {Vorname Name and Vorname Name},
  title     = {Titel},
  journal   = {Zeitschriftentitel},
  year      = {2004},
  volume    = {Jg. 106},
  number    = {H. 4},
  pages     = {S. 28-31},
  month     = {12},
  groups    = {1-Einleitung},
}

@PhdThesis{Phd00,
  author        = {Vorname Name},
  title         = {Titel},
  school        = {Universität},
  year          = {2009},
}

@TechReport{Techreport00,
  author      = {Vorname Name and Vorname Name},
  title       = {Titel},
  institution = {Institution},
  year        = {2015},
}

@Manual{Manual00,
  title        = {Titel},
  organization = {Organisation},
  year         = {2017},
  location     = {New York},
}

@Conference{Conf00,
  author    = {Vorname Name},
  title     = {Title},
  booktitle = {Konferenzname},
  year      = {2015},
  timestamp = {2016.04.29},
}

@Book{Buch01,
  title     = {Titel},
  publisher = {Verlag},
  year      = {1996},
  editor    = {Vorname Name},
  volume    = {Auflage},
  location  = {Ort},
}

@Book{Buch00,
  title     = {Titel},
  publisher = {Verlag},
  year      = {1996},
  author    = {Vorname Name},
  editor    = {Vorname Name},
  volume    = {Auflage},
  location  = {Ort},
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use the entrykeys of your `.bib` entries as the citation key in your document, which I absolutely can not recommend, your best bet is changing the `labelalpha` template. Remove the `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\thefield{entrykey}}` and add

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field{citekey}
  }
}
```

The `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\thefield{entrykey}}` would not work as expected because it did not take the `extraalpha` field into account that was calculated based on the standard labels produced by Biber, where `Buch00` and `Buch01` would both end up with "Nam96" and hence "a" and "b" had to be added to make the labels unique.

I think this practice is a bad idea because it goes against the idea that the entrykeys are a purely internal designation for your entries and that `biblatex` and Biber should calculate a useful label that appears in the output.

The MWE stripped of packages irrelevant to the question and comments and modernised to work with a current version of `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,ngerman]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
  giveninits=true,
  maxbibnames=99,
  maxcitenames=1,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field{citekey}
  }
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{% 
  andothers = {et\,al\adddot},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space} 


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Article00,
  author    = {Vorname Name and Vorname Name},
  title     = {Titel},
  journal   = {Zeitschriftentitel},
  year      = {2004},
  volume    = {106},
  number    = {4},
  pages     = {28-31},
  month     = {12},
}
@PhdThesis{Phd00,
  author        = {Vorname Name},
  title         = {Titel},
  school        = {Universität},
  year          = {2009},
}
@TechReport{Techreport00,
  author      = {Vorname Name and Vorname Name},
  title       = {Titel},
  institution = {Institution},
  year        = {2015},
}
@Manual{Manual00,
  title        = {Titel},
  organization = {Organisation},
  year         = {2017},
  location     = {New York},
}
@Conference{Conf00,
  author    = {Vorname Name},
  title     = {Title},
  booktitle = {Konferenzname},
  year      = {2015},
}
@Book{Buch01,
  title     = {Titel},
  publisher = {Verlag},
  year      = {1996},
  editor    = {Vorname Name},
  volume    = {Auflage},
  location  = {Ort},
}
@Book{Buch00,
  title     = {Titel},
  publisher = {Verlag},
  year      = {1996},
  author    = {Vorname Name},
  editor    = {Vorname Name},
  volume    = {Auflage},
  location  = {Ort},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Buch00,Buch01,Article00,Phd00,Techreport00,Manual00,Conf00}

\printbibliography[nottype=manual]
\printbibliography[type=manual]
\end{document}
```

[image: Buch00 and Buch01]

Quite related: [use tag as biblatex key](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481732/35864). Note also that while elsewhere `biblatex` calls the entry key of an entry `entrykey`, here it is called `citekey`. The name `entrykey` will be valid in future Biber versions (https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/259).